# Evaluating the limit of the sequence $b_n = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}$ where $a_n = (2^n+3^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

I want to find the limit of the sequence $b_n$.
With some manipulations I am able to obtain $$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n= 3\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+ \left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^k\right)^{1/k}}  $$

I can not proceed any further. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: See also: [$a_n=(2^n+3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $b_n=\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}$,then what is the limit of $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3844671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$a_n = \left( 2^n + 3^n \right)^{1/n} = 3 \left( 1 + \left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$

which tends to $3$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. So
$$\frac{1}{a_n} \sim \frac{1}{3}$$
and you can use Cesaro to see that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} \sim \frac{n}{3}$$

So you deduce that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}} = 3$$

Comment: Nice, it has been very long time I studied/revisited Cesaro's theorem. Need to brush up!