# $a_n=(2^n+3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $b_n=\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}$,then what is the limit of $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $a_n=(2^n+3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $b_n=\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}$,then what is the limit of  $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

**Solution:** We have $$b_n=\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}$$
$$\implies b_n=\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2^i+3^i)^{\frac{1}{i}}}}$$

$$\implies  b_n=\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3\big[\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^i+1\big]^{\frac{1}{i}}}}$$

$$\implies  b_n=\dfrac{3n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\big[\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^i+1\big]^{\frac{1}{i}}}}$$

On taking limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$,we get

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{3n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\big[\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^i+1\big]^{\frac{1}{i}}}}$.

Now, I got stuck here, I'm not getting how to handle the denominator...Please give  suggestions(**NOT ANSWER**)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove that $a_n \to 3$. Now use the fact that if a sequence $(c_n)$ converges so does the sequence of averages  $\frac {c_1+c+_2+...+c_n} n$.

Comment: :I got this,I've proved $a_n\rightarrow 3$ using the logarithms.Please tell me how to compute this($a_n\rightarrow 3$) limit using Squeeze theorem.

Comment: Lower bound $3$, upper bound $2^{1/n} 3$